# Is there a cross-platform way to get the name of the parent process in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, pnpm

I'm working on an npm package initializer, that is, a program that runs when the user runs the `npm init <my-package-initializer>` command.

npm is not the only package manager for Node.js any more, yarn is also quite popular and pnpm is a personal favorite of mine and I want to support all three. The easy way is to ask the user which package manager they prefer or provide a command-line switch like [CRA does](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#selecting-a-package-manager).

But the user has already shown their preference by running, say, `yarn create` instead of `npm init`. It feels annoying to ask again. We could just check if `yarn` or `pnpm` is our parent process.

Is there a cross-platform way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future googlers, I ended up using the following snippet. I use it for picking the default choice but I still ask the user explicitly for their package manager preference, better safe than sorry.

```
function getPackageManager() {
    // This environment variable is set by npm and yarn but pnpm seems less consistent
    const agent = process.env.npm_config_user_agent;

    if (!agent) {
        // This environment variable is set on Linux but I'm not sure about other OSes.
        const parent = process.env._;

        if (!parent) {
            // No luck, assume npm
            return "npm";
        }

        if (parent.endsWith("pnpx") || parent.endsWith("pnpm")) return "pnpm";
        if (parent.endsWith("yarn")) return "yarn";

        // Assume npm for anything else
        return "npm";
    }

    const [program] = agent.split("/");

    if (program === "yarn") return "yarn";
    if (program === "pnpm") return "pnpm";

    // Assume npm
    return "npm";
}
```

Comment: `process.env._` is not guaranteed even in Linux (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293000), consider checking against whether `process.env.npm_command` is defined to indicate `npm`, or if `process.env.npm_execpath` is defined and ends with `yarn.js` to indicate `yarn`